# how to find out when an EC2 instance was last stopped

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

Is there a way to easily find out when an EC2 instance was last stopped? I am able to get the launch time from `ec2.get_only_instances()` by looking at the `launch_time` variable. However, it doesn't look as if the stop time is stored in any of the metadata.

We will probably be implementing this using the `rc#.d` scripts for shutdown, but I am just wondering if I could get that information via `boto`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the `reason` variable of `stopped` instances:

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("eu-west-1")
reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
for r in reservations:
    for i in r.instances:
        if i.state == 'stopped':
            print "%s [%s] %s" % (i.id, i.state, i.reason)
```

Output:

```
i-11223344 [stopped] User initiated (2013-12-20 13:59:08 GMT)
```

This works also for `terminated` instances (as long as they are still displayed).

Comment: Is there a known situation on which it won't print the time stamp? It works well to me except that it ends the print after `User initiated` and it does not provide me the timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

I think that better practice would be:

```
import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("eu-west-1")
reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
instances = []
for reservation in reservations:
    for instance in reservation.instances:
        if "Name" in instance.tags.keys():
            instances.append((instance.tags["Name"],
                              instance.get_console_output().timestamp))
```

You can also replace the `if` and get whatever you want, but `instance.get_console_output().timestamp` is the right way to get instance's stopped timestamp

Comment: This approach is the only one that allowed to properly get the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this please,it is returning timestamp within ec2 name which have stopped at aws and its color red. Note that set an aws profile environment which have contains credential before run it.

```
import boto.ec2    

class i_color:
  red   = '\033[31m'
  reset = '\033[0m'

def name(i):
  if 'Name' in i.tags:
    n = i.tags['Name']
    n = i_color.red + n + i_color.reset
  return n

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
reservations = conn.get_all_instances()
for r in reservations:
    for i in r.instances:
        if i.state == 'stopped':
           print "%s [%s] %s" % (name(i),i.state,i.reason)
```

**Sample output:**

```
test-ec2-temp05 [stopped] User initiated (2016-08-02 09:00:43 GMT)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import boto3
from prettytable import PrettyTable

cli = boto3.client('ec2')
resp = cli.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'instance-state-name',
            'Values': [
                'stopped',
            ]
        },
    ],
    MaxResults=1000,
)

table = PrettyTable()
table.field_names = ["Name", "ID", "State", "Reason"]

for r in resp["Reservations"]:
    for i in r["Instances"]:
        name = ''
        for t in i["Tags"]:
            if t["Key"] == "Name":
                name = t["Value"]

        table.add_row([name, i["InstanceId"], i["State"]["Name"],
                       i["StateTransitionReason"]])

print(table.get_string(sortby="Reason"))
```

**Output:**

```
+-------------------+---------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+
|       Name        |          ID         |  State  |                  Reason                  |
+-------------------+---------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+
| server-name-tag-1 | i-0a12b3056c789012a | stopped | User initiated (2017-02-27 20:20:00 GMT) |
| server-name-tag-2 | i-1b12b3956c789012b | stopped | User initiated (2018-02-27 20:20:00 GMT) |
| server-name-tag-3 | i-2c12b3856c789012c | stopped | User initiated (2019-02-27 20:20:00 GMT) |
| server-name-tag-4 | i-3d12b3756c789012d | stopped | User initiated (2020-02-27 20:20:00 GMT) |
+-------------------+---------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+
```